# Getting nullpointerexception while returning a value from static method in java

Tags: java

I am trying to return a String from static method and assigning to a string inside another static method.

```
               public static ArrayList val(){    
                  String a = "Some value";    
                  String someString = identifyString(a);    
                  //some code     
                  }    

               private static String identifyString(String a){    
                   String[] ac = "";    
                   String b = "";    
                   String c = "";
                   ac = a.split(some pattern);    
                      if(some condition){    
                                 b = a[0];  
                                 c = a[1];
                                 return b+"-"+c;    
                                 }    
                     }
```

return b+"-"+c is throwing nullpointerexception.Please Help. I also made "someString" as static but then too its giving nullpointerexception.

Comment: `return a + "-" + c` can never throw that exception. Post the stack trace please.

Comment: `String[] ac = ""; ` won't even compile.  Please post real code.

Comment: it is compiling however in my case the values are being fetched from table and it is also forming a string if i assign a+"-"+c to some string variable, only when it is about to return it is throwing the nullpointerexception.

Comment: i am assigning String[] ac = null;

Answer (score 0):

You are returning values only when "if" condition is satisfied. The program won't return anything if the "if" condition is not satisfied.

Make sure you always return something no matter what

Comment: That's true, but doesn't answer the question. OP didn't post his full/real code.

Comment: it is compiling however in my case the values are being fetched from table and it is also forming a string if i assign a+"-"+c to some string variable, only when it is about to return it is throwing the nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with the code - perhaps you could clarify what you are trying to achieve?  The fact the methods are static is not relevant and assigning the empty strings is not necessary (and doesn't make sense for the string array).

I'm guessing you meant:
b = ac[0];
c = ac[1];

return b+"-"+c;

You should also guard against the split returning an array of size under 2, give the return array a generic type in the method descriptor for val() and use more descriptive field names.